# How require API promise resolve in node

Tags: node.js, api, twilio

I want to consume the `twilio API` in the `index.js`

`twilio.js`

```
    function displayMessage() {
      client
        .messages("SM781294ff3af4a39a449966abd9335")
        .fetch()
        .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
    }
    
    // displayMessage();
    
    module.exports = displayMessage();
```

**index.js**:

```
    const twilio = require("../twilio.js");
    
    const message = twilio;
    console.log(message);
```

**Result**
`twilio.js` is resolving and logging to console correctly the API callback result
`index.j`s is **giving result of undefined**.

**what is the correct usage/syntax of the promise when required**?

Answer (score 1):

Well, usually we do not execute the method before we exporting it. We just export the function itself.

Also you did `(message) => console.log(message.sid)` without curly brackets which means you return the expression on the right. `console.log()` returns `undefined`

Also you even forgot to return anything in the function

```
function displayMessage() {
  return client
    .messages("SM781294ff3af4a39a449966abd9335")
    .fetch()
    .then((message) => message.sid);
}


module.exports = displayMessage;
```

Remember that your response is an promise.

```
const twilio = require("../twilio.js");

const result = twilio();
result.then(message => {
    console.log(message)
});
```

Comment: @dflow could you show me what you want to achieve so i can help you further

Comment: I would like to use the object in index.js. not sure how to access the resolved .then (message) as const newMessage = message;

Comment: @dflow the point is you cannot. it will always be an promise that needs to be resolved

Comment: ok so what is the correct way to await the results and display them?

Comment: @dflow i dont know. i dont see your code i see only what you posted. i dont know what you want to achieve